# handling sub-domains in IIS for a web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I am have a web application on local IIS (mylocalsite.com)
What settings I need, so that I can handle all subdomains of my local site, like

user1.mylocalsite.com
user2.mylocalsite.com
anything.mylocalsite.com

All urls will point to same index page from where I can seperate subdomain and load page accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your description is not that clear, my initial thought would that you can setup different `Bindings` in IIS to cater for all the subdomains.

In IIS 7, right click your website -> Edit Bindings -> Add..

But my guess would be that you may need to do this from code, since users are added to your system (assuming user/sub-domain model). For this I refer you to

- [Create Binding in in IIS (iis.net)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/285/provisioning-sample-in-c/#CreateBinding)
- [Cool new IIS7 Features and APIs - ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/20/Cool-new-IIS7-Features-and-APIs.aspx)
- [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)