# Subdomain URL Rediretion In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis, subdomain, redirect

I am new in MVC, I have a list of url redirection:

•website1.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\1

•website2.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\2

This is a dynamic mapping like this: websiteN.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\N

How can I do this in MVC, Do I need to use routing? or I need only URL redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a duplicate question.**

Everything you need can be done in IIS.

please visit this Stack link:

[handling sub-domains in IIS for a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960442/handling-sub-domains-in-iis-for-a-web-application)

(same user asked this question and reposted [How can we make an ASP.NET MVC4 route based on a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632057/how-can-we-make-an-asp-net-mvc4-route-based-on-a-subdomain))

you can get more detailed information:

http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/04/aspnet-iis-dns-records-sub-domain-on.html
http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm

Comment: Thank you Dave, In last post the solution did not worked for me in MVC.

Comment: @Houshang.Karami, this is NOT an MVC issue. It's an IIS issue. MVC Mapping DOES not deal with subdomains.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking there should be routing or URL redirection for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar situation where I needed to make sure that the language code was in the url.

My solution was to write an http module. You'll want this module to inspect the request and see what subdomain the request is under. If it is a subdomain, then you'll want to redirect them to the correct directory under domain.com